# Cómo obtener los valores con mayores registros de varios campos en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un proyecto en el cual estoy trabajando, pero me he atorado con un `query`, dentro de mi proyecto tengo la siguiente tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La cual obtengo con el `query`:

```
SELECT no_carpeta, sector, MAX(colonia), MAX(delito), MAX(hora_delito), COUNT(colonia) FROM scpd_incidencia GROUP BY sector
```

como pueden ver tengo unos `MAX(colonia)`, `MAX(delito)`, `MAX(hora_delito)`, lo que pretendía hacer era sacar el **Valor con más registros**, *por ejemplo*:

```
BJ1 NAPOLES | AMPLIACION NAPOLES | ROBO A CASA HABITACION CON VIOLENCIA | 12:30
```

sin embargo creo que `MAX()` no me ayudara en ese aspecto, he intentado hacer un `count(colonia)` pero eso me arroja un **3, 1, 1**, *véase en la imagen*.

mis datos registrados son estos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero obtener es el **valor que mas registros tiene** de cada uno de los campos `colonia`, `delito`, `hora_delito`, agrupados por el `sector`, *por ejemplo*:

```
BJ1 NAPOLES | AMPLIACION NAPOLES | ROBO A CASA HABITACION CON VIOLENCIA | 12:30
```

Esto porque, como se puede ver en los datos registrados, *véase la imagen*

> `BJ1 NAPOLES` tiene 3 delitos, de los cuales `ROBO A CASA HABITACION CON VIOLENCIA` tiene 2 registros **(valor con mas registros)**, la `hora_delito` con **mayor registro** son `12:30` con 2, y en el campo `colonia` el **registro mayor** seria `AMPLIACION NAPOLES`, con 2 registros.

Adjunto un [CSV](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E5kR1Gpy9vW5-WEbGxZWQM1NwftaHExy) de mis datos.

Hay manera de lograrlo, gracias por su atención y ayuda.

Comment: Sí, hay manera de lograrlo. Modifica la pregunta y pásanos la base de datos en SQL (phpMyAdmin, Exportar) y aclara un poco mejor qué quieres obtener a partir de los datos de muestra que nos envíes, pon más ejemplos si es necesario. Se trata de una consulta de totales y selección, no salen de forma directa, tienen su miga pero, como todo, una vez entendidas ya van solas. Envía esos datos y será un placer explicártela.

Comment: Hola @David hay un detalle con el export con gusto se los pasaría pero no tengo esos privilegios, en un momento modifico la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: Aunque sea un volcado en CSV que podamos importar... que, en capturas de pantalla, es inviable

Comment: Listo el CSV !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, aquí la tienes:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT sector,colonia,n n_delitos_colonia FROM (
        SELECT sector,colonia,COUNT(*) n FROM artes GROUP BY 1,2
      ) c1 JOIN (
        SELECT sector,MAX(n) n FROM (
            SELECT sector,colonia,COUNT(*) n FROM artes GROUP BY 1,2      
          ) c1 GROUP BY 1
      ) c2 USING(sector,n)
  ) c2 JOIN (
    SELECT sector,h,n n_delitos_h FROM (
        SELECT sector,HOUR(hora_delito) h,COUNT(*) n FROM artes GROUP BY 1,2
      ) c1 JOIN (
        SELECT sector,MAX(n) n FROM (
            SELECT sector,HOUR(hora_delito) h,COUNT(*) n FROM artes GROUP BY 1,2      
          ) c1 GROUP BY 1
      ) c2 USING(sector,n)
  ) c3 USING(sector) JOIN (
    SELECT sector,delito,n n_delitos_tipo FROM (
        SELECT sector,delito,COUNT(*) n FROM artes GROUP BY 1,2
      ) c1 JOIN (
        SELECT sector,MAX(n) n FROM (
            SELECT sector,delito,COUNT(*) n FROM artes GROUP BY 1,2      
          ) c1 GROUP BY 1
      ) c2 USING(sector,n)
  ) c4 USING(sector);
```

Pruébala y, si es lo que necesitas, explico cómo he llegado a conseguirla.

El resultado es algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una pregunta, por qué en la hora `h` no se ven los minutos??

Comment: Porque he truncado los minutos para que pudieras obtener un histograma, si le quitas la función HOUR() los recuperarás.

Comment: Si, me di cuenta del dato, me ha servido un tanto tu respuesta, le hecho modificaciones eliminando los resultados de `n_delitos_colonia`, `n_delitos_h`, `n_delitos_tipo`, muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¡Genial! Temía que con un acceso parcial al sistema no pudieras implementarla... Si necesitas cualquier aclaración sobre la misma, estoy a tu disposición para ampliar la respuesta detallando lo que necesites. Recuerda aceptarla y votar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY
```

En esa consulta te generará inconsistencias en los datos que deseas obtener, puedes hacerlo con una subconsulta, añadiendo una clausula WHERE con un IN () para agrupar por sector:

```
SELECT no_carpeta, sector, MAX(colonia), MAX(delito), MAX(hora_delito), colonia FROM 
scpd_incidencia WHERE sector IN ( SELECT DISTINCT sector FROM scpd_incidencia);
```